# Custom report period for getSharePointSiteUsageDetail API

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

Pretty new to powershell and API so wanted to ask about the following. I have been trying to get some site usage details by calling this MS Graph API "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D30')"

By calling it will give me the usage data for the last 30 days.

What i wanted to know is that will it be possible to select a custom report period. Lets say the last 30 days before the 10th of April 2023. So the usage data from 10 of March till 10 of April.

Anything i should try, advice?

Thanks

Tried "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D30',startDate='2023-03-11',endDate='2023-04-10')" but not possible.

Comment: Check the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0 You can specify only the period or a specific day, not both.

Answer (score 0):

As @user2250152 said, you can specify only the period or a specific day, not both.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D30')
```

Or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(startDate='2023-03-11',endDate='2023-04-10')
```